# Data Storage for Games

Tags: c#, xna

I am about 20% into my first game and was wondering what the best way to store local data was. I need to store item stats, such as levels, damage per level, etc, in a database sort of fashion. Is it considered good practice to store such data in a "local" database and then query using SQL? Or is there another way? I am working in .NET 4 and XNA 4

Thanks!

Comment: [This question on GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-to-choose-how-to-store-data) is similar, maybe you can find it useful (the only difference is that it isn't focused on a concrete framework)

Comment: Unless you have very very specific performance needs, and need to query the data by arbitrary attributes, using an embedded DB and SQL or EF is a good enough general purpose approach. (Assuming XNA will let you get a plain old file handle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a general rule and this is one of many things that simply depends on what you are doing and how you will be using your data.

There are many ways to store data. I normally see binary file formats being the most common in games. If you want to use SQL without using an actual database server, though, I'd recommend looking at *embedded* databases, such as SQLite, SQL Server Compact Edition, or Firebird (there are others). These store data in a single file, but you can query them using SQL.

Comment: But will the user be allowed to edit the embedded database? That is my biggest fear. I don't mind if the user cheats by hacking the memory (it will be a single player game after all), but I don't want it to be as easy as opening a database file.

Comment: You can password protect it. I've done that with both SQL Compact and Firebird in the past.

Comment: I decided to use SQLLite, we will see how it goes. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is actually to use the built in XNA support for Title and User file-based storage. Please take a look at [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb200105%28v=xnagamestudio.30%29.aspx) for the MSFT XNA storage best practices.

Comment: While a good hint, user storage only solves the problem of where to store the data, not how to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization. If you want readable files, choose XML/JSON serializer. If you need performance: protobuf or manual binary serialization.

Comment: Serialisation is arguably better for savegames that get written out in batches, which might not be what the OP is trying to do. (Seeing as he mentions some statistics which might need to be updated constantly throughout gameplay.)